# ScalaJS fullLinkJS errors

Tags: scala.js, playscalajs

I upgraded my Play+ScalaJS project from ScalaJS 0.6.32 to 1.4.0 several weeks ago.  All has been working fine in development.  Today I tried to deploy it and thus executed `fullLinkJS` for the first time.  It generated a number of errors:

```
sbt:browser> fullLinkJS
[info] Full optimizing /Users/bwbecker/oat/src/oat3/_browser/target/scala-2.12/browser-opt
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/views/bulkmail/BMailCreateView.scala(125:43:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/views/components/filteredTable/FilteredBMailTable.scala(81:53:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/models/Autocomplete.scala(156:18:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/views/virtualq/QueueAddEditView.scala(90:52:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/views/bulkmail/edit/BMailSendView.scala(273:62:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
[error] c91662c1ae832d6a8493/oat/browser/views/bulkmail/TemplateListView.scala(42:64:Apply): scala.Dynamic expected but any found for tree of type org.scalajs.ir.Trees$JSSelect
...
```

I've looked at about a dozen of the referenced lines in the source code.  Most of them refer to either a Play route or invoke the `url` method.  The rest of them involve a call to jQuery.

The project has a cross-platform subproject.  That one does the fullLinkJS just fine.  There's also a client-specific ScalaJS project.  That's where the errors are happening.

I'm using ScalaJS 1.4.0 and Play 2.6.25.

Suggestions on how to procede?

### Later, after reading reply from @sjrd

A sample of the offending code:

```
private val wapp = routes.oat.wapp.controllers.BMailCtrl
...
window.location.href = wapp.edit(emailId).url // this is the line flagged with the error
```

`window` is defined in `org.scalajs.dom` as a `js.Dynamic`.

`routes` is defined in my code as `val routes: js.Dynamic = global.jsRoutes`. The `js.Dynamic` type annotation is what is inferred by IntelliJ.

Aha!  `global` is defined in `scala.scalajs.js` as extending `scala.Dynamic`.  But I believe the `jsRoutes` should be interpreted as a `js.Dynamic`.  It's the routes produced by the Play server.

It looks like I need to change how I access those guys.  Researching, particularly, [Scala.js GlobalScope](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/global-scope.html).

### Still Later -- the fix

I'm recording what I did here so I can mark sjrd's answer as "the answer".

As noted, most of my IR validation errors were on lines of the form

```
window.location.href = wapp.edit(emailId).url
```

`href` has a type of `String` and `url` is `js.Dynamic` but produces a string.  I think therein lies the problem.

The fix, however, was simple: add `toString`:

```
window.location.href = wapp.edit(emailId).url.toString
```

All the other IR validation errors were variants of this with a similar fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors you see are "IR checking errors". They mean that there are inconsistencies in the `.sjsir` files that are produced by the compiler. By default, they are only checked for `fullOpt` tasks, which is why you have not seen them before. However, that does not mean the IR is any more valid for `fastOpt` (it's the same IR!), so the error was always there (latent), but only surfaces now. Having IR checking errors means that the optimizer, or simply the JavaScript code generator, can produce nonsensical results.

(IR checking errors are also similar to [`VerifyError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html)s on the JVM.

Broadly speaking, there are 3 sources of IR checking errors:

- Using binary incompatible versions of transitive libraries can cause IR checking errors in some rare cases, even when no [linking error](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/linking-errors.html) arises.
- Bugs in the Scala.js core toolchain (compiler, linker)
- A particular known (and somewhat intentional) unsoundness issue in the Scala.js type system: [js.Dynamic <: scala.Dynamic causes unsoundness in the IR](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1385).

What you are experiencing is the latter issue. It is quite rare. Basically, it happens if you assign (through `=` or passing a function argument, etc.) a value of type `js.Dynamic` to a value of type `scala.Dynamic`. For example:

```scala
val jsDyn = js.Dynamic.literal(foo = "bar")
val scalaDyn: scala.Dynamic = jsDyn
```

The type checker accepts that snippet because, at compile-time, `js.Dynamic` extends `scala.Dynamic`. This is necessary for `js.Dynamic` to expose its dynamism in the first place, so we cannot change that. However, at link- and run-time, `js.Dynamic` is a JavaScript type (because it extends `js.Any`) and `scala.Dynamic` is a Scala type, and JavaScript types are never subtypes of Scala types.

---

So where does that leave you?

Look at the code pointed by the error messages. You will need to identify a place where a `js.Dynamic` (or any other JS type that extends `scala.Dynamic`, but `js.Dynamic` is typically the only one like that) is assigned to a `scala.Dynamic`.

It is extremely rare to write `scala.Dynamic` (or just `Dynamic`) as a type by hand (and doing so is probably always a mistake), but it could be the case that it is *inferred* by the compiler, for example if you have two branches of an if/else that return two different subtypes of `scala.Dynamic`.

This is all I can say without seeing the problematic code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, @sjrd.  Is this new behaviour with ScalaJS 1.x?  I didn't run into it with the 0.6 series.

Comment: In terms of offending code, many look like:
   private val wapp = routes.oat.wapp.controllers.BMailCtrl
   window.location.href = wapp.edit(emailId).url             // this is the line flagged

window is defined in org.scalajs.dom as a `js.Dynamic`.
routes is defined in my code as `  val routes: js.Dynamic = global.jsRoutes`. The `js.Dynamic` is what is inferred by IntelliJ.

Comment: The fact that IR integrity is checked by default in fullOpt is new in 1.x. But the underlying validity rules are not new, and so the latent problem already existed in 0.6.x.

Comment: Try inserting explicit `js.Dynamic` types in various relevant parts of the code, to narrow down where the `scala.Dynamic` comes from.